# Galaxy Note 2 Locked

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, custom-roms

I was in 4.1.2 of Samsung Galaxy Note 2 which I unlocked using *#197328640# but today I updated to Kitkat Based DN3 ROM. It says "Emergency Calls Only"

Is there a solution out? How about unlocking? DO I have to buy a new IMEI or is it free?

Any help will be highly supportive. Thanks

Comment: Sounds to me like you just need to reactivate it.

Comment: Umm, How do I do that? I am really new to these things. Please help. @IAmTheSquidward

Comment: What carrier are you using?

Comment: Its from the UK. My brother got me.I am really not sure. Is there a way to check?

Comment: So you don't have it on a carrier yet?

Comment: I guess, the way I should phrase it is like this... You don't have service on it yet or you do?

Comment: Err..., I think No.

Comment: If you don't know, you don't have service... When it says "Emergency Calls Only," that just means it's not activated on a carrier.  To make calls, send texts, get data, etc, you need to subscribe to cell service through a carrier.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16468/discussion-between-xdnp-and-iamthesquidward).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have any cellular functions apart from placing emergency calls, you have to have an actual cellular plan through a carrier.

Picture it this way: If you buy a land line phone for your house, take it out of the box, program speed dials, and set it on your table without plugging it into a phone line, you won't be able to receive any phone calls. Your cell phone is simply a tablet until you activate a cellular plan through your carrier for it.

Also, the ability to place emergency calls is a feature on all cell phones that is not dependent on carriers.

Here is a list of [UK Carriers](http://www.uswitch.com/mobiles/networks/).